# Where did ServiceStack.Common.Utils.ReflectionUtils go from 3.9.69 to 4.0.20

Tags: servicestack

I can't seem to find what to use instead of this, but here's what I had before:

```
using ServiceStack.Common.Utils;

...

public Profile Put(ProfileUpdate req) {
    var cred = this.GetCredential();
    this.AskUser();
    var data = Db.GetById<Profile>(cred.UserId);

    ReflectionUtils.PopulateObject<Profile, ProfileUpdatable>(data, req);
```

Now I can't find where Utils or ReflectionUtils or PopulateObject has gone in version 4.0.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions have been replaced with these [auto mapping functions, documented here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping).

So you would use:

```cs
var data = Db.GetById<Profile>(cred.UserId);
data.PopulateWith(req);
```

Comment: You know, I kind of saw something about the auto mapping but didn't quite see the methods.  Thanks so much for this!

Comment: @EricClark You're welcome :) Good luck with your project